# How to Pass Values to Parent Class in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a mainActivity Named A. In that Main Activity I have a View which i am doing some calculations. After finishing the Calculation in the View. I need to pass the Sum to Main Activity A.

How we can do it in Kotlin

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This doesn't sound like it be a good idea, why do you want to do this?

Comment: Can you elaborate the usecase in details

Comment: The description of your question lacks details as to what exactly you're trying to ask or achieve. Add more details and elaborate. Post any relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general way would be to provide a callback but I can't help further without details.

It would be the same as view.setOnClickListener but something like

```
calculatorView.onCalculationDoneListener{ result ->
  //called in mainactivity, put code that executes when finished here
}
```

But as others have said, in **most** cases you wouldn't want to put calculation logic into views themself.